# Having to Print in order for an if then statement to work

Tags: java

I am currently trying to make a little game and it is all working out so far. I came into this one problem that I managed to fix but I don't really like the way I fixed it. The code with the problem is:

```
if (x > -930 && x <= 0 && x > -1825 &&  y > -365 && y <= 0) {
    area = 1;
} else if (x <= -930 && x <= -1825  && x >= -2735 && y >= -365 && y <= 0) {
    area = 2;
}
```

It doesn't really work out so well. The else if part doesn't run. The way I fixed it is:

```
System.out.println("X: " + x);
System.out.println("Y: " + y);
if (x > -930 && x <= 0 && x > -1825 &&  y > -365 && y <= 0) {
    area = 1;
} else if (x <= -930 && x <= -1825  && x >= -2735 && y >= -365 && y <= 0) {
    area = 2;
    System.out.println("Area 2");
}
```

All I did was just print the X and Y and the else statement started running. But what happens, is the output console is just flooded with the prints. Does anyone know a way I can achieve the same output but without printing anything?
(Note: Both codes are inside a while (true) loop).

Comment: Research OR (||) statements. Your boolean logic is flawed.

Comment: This sounds like a race condition issue. If so, another way to solve is to use Thread.sleep, like `Thead.sleep(10)`

Comment: @ControlAltDel, that worked. Thank you.

Comment: `x <= -930 && x <= -1825  && x >= -2735 && y >= -365 && y <= 0` simplifies to `x <= -1825 && x >= -2735 && y >= -365 && y <= 0` and `x > -930 && x <= 0 && x > -1825 &&  y > -365 && y <= 0` simplifies to `x > -930 && x <= 0 && y > -365 && y <= 0`

Comment: @ControlAltDel this is hardly a solution, even if it works (now). If there is really a race condition in the code it should be resolved in the correct way.

Comment: @Henry totally agree with you. But fixing the race condition requires seeing code that isn't included with the question, and possibly skills/knowledge that the OP doesn't possess.

Comment: Can you add currant/wrong output and expected output? Because I don't think that by just including code to print something will change any other logic. May be you can share running code on any of the online IDE.

Comment: Are x and y local variables? If not they may change during your condition check. But we can't see that in this section of your code.

Comment: @ControlAltDel what you say is all true, but there is already too much lousy software in the world we should not encourage more of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
        if (x <= 0 && x > -1825 &&  y > -365 && y <= 0) {
            area = 1;
        }
        else if (x <= -1825  && x >= -2735 && y >= -365 && y <= 0) {
            area = 2;
            System.out.println("Area 2");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    final int localX = x;
    final int localY = y;

    if (localX <= -1825 && localX >= -2735 && localY >= -365 && localY <= 0) {
        area = 1;
    }
    else if (localX > -930 && localX <= 0 && localY > -365 && localY <= 0) {
        area = 2;
    }
```

it it works you're using multiple Threads and should read about multithreading, especially race conditions and concurreny.